# JavaScript newbie issue about inheritance not working

Tags: javascript

My sample is simple. I have a Person object that has two properties -- a 'name', and a function called 'sayName'. My objective is to allow a subtype called Woman inherit from it.

Here's the sort code snippet:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sayName = function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    };
}

function Woman(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Woman.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype, {
   constructor : {
       enumerable: true,
       configurable: true,
       writable: true,
       value: Woman
   } 
});

var woman = new Woman("Jane");
// I'M GETTING AN ERROR ON THIS LINE, SAYING UNDEFINED FUNCTION
woman.sayName();
```

Now I do know that an alternative is to attach the sayName() function to the prototype. But based on my reading, JavaScript is supposed to check the Woman object's own properties for "sayName" (which it won't find), then it will look at Woman object's prototype for "sayName" (which it won't find). Then it's supposed to ascend up to the Person object and look for "sayName" in its own properties, and it should find it there. But it seems like it's not doing that.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 4):

> Then it's supposed to ascend up to the Person object and look for "sayName" in its own properties, and it should find it there.

Which `Person` object? You are only plugging `Person.prototype` into `Woman`'s prototype chain, but `Person.prototype` doesn't have a `sayName` property either. You are never calling `Person`, so a `Person` instance cannot exist.

You are forgetting to call the parent's constructor on the child's instance:

```
function Woman(name) {
    Person.call(this, name);
}
```

However, `sayName` should really be defined on `Person.prototype`.

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log(this.name);
};

function Woman(name) {
    Person.call(this, name);
}

Woman.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype, {
   constructor : {
       enumerable: true,
       configurable: true,
       writable: true,
       value: Woman
   } 
});
```